# Does working with primitives in Java create new Objects?

Tags: java

AFAIK the following code...

```
void foo () {

Integer i1 = new Integer(2);
Integer i2 = new Integer(2);
Integer i3 = new Integer(2);

i3 = i1 + i2;
}
```

... will actually create a new Integer Object when executing the + operator and assign its address to i3.

Does the same hold for primitive types also? I.e.:

```
void foo () {

int i1 = 2;
int i2 = 2;
int i3 = 2;

i3 = i1 + i2;
}
```

... Or will i3 in this case keep it's address in memory and get's the result of i1 + i2 copied to that address?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The definition of a primitive value is that it is not an object. I think you should be able to answer your question by thinking about it for a few seconds.

Comment: You asked an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me answer by turning your question a bit upside-down:

```
Integer i1 = new Integer(2);
Integer i2 = new Integer(2);
Integer i3 = new Integer(2);

i3 = i1 + i2;
```

vs.

```
int i1 = 2;
int i2 = 2;
int i3 = 2;

i3 = i1 + i2;
```

In both cases the *exact same thing* happens to the `i3` variable: its value gets overwritten and its address stays the same. The only difference is in the *meaning* of those values.

NB. Since the `Integer` instances you use don't escape the method, the actual native code may not make any allocations at all and may be exactly equivalent in both cases.

Answer (score 3):

Your terminology is a bit confused.... the value of `i3` isn't an address (or reference) at all, it's *just* the integer value. But no, the example you've given won't create any `Integer` objects.

Answer (score 2):

A primitive is not an object.... so no :))

Answer (score 2):

Primitive is not an object - no.